# High speed counter with step control

Tags: counter, dds

I am trying to build my own DDS.  I want to make a lookup table (eeprom)that controls steps of a counter and  then feed it into a DAC to make a wave form ( something like that Direct Digital Synthesizers do).

It seems all parts are straight forward except the counter. Normally, counters start counting from 0-2^n-1.  For example a 256 step counter starts from 0 and counts one by one to 255. Now I need a counter that can count with controlled steps (jump). For example 0,10,20,...,250  or 0-4,8,..    And these steps are selected programmatically with count speed around 100MHz.

Anyone knows an IC that does the job?  I heard Analog Devices has parts like that but I don't know under which product group should I look for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build your own counter with adjustable steps in a CPLD or FPGA.

Better yet, just implement the entire DDS in a small FPGA, memory and all.  There's next to no logic design work in it, e.g. Xilinx provide free DDS IP.

Comment: Unfortunately I have zero experience on FPGA. I can work with AVRs but their speed does not suffice for this purpose.

Comment: FPGA's are not the scary bogeyman that some people seem to believe.  If they're the tool that you need to use to do the task, you should learn to use them.

Comment: Since your first answer time I started searching the web about FPGAs. It seems that if someone knows prograramming, they should not be very difficult. I just started reading some Xilinx datasheets and I think they have internal RAM that may eliminate need for EEPROM (is that?). I was thinking about XC2S100-PQ208. Can it provide 100MHz speed for this purpose?

Comment: I wouldn't be using a Spartan2, they're quite old.  Look at an XC6SLX4, which are current-generation Xilinx FPGA's, or even an XC6SLX9.  They do contain memory; it's not EEPROM, it's actually RAM, but when the FPGA configuration is loaded (from an attached NV memory chip) you can have it initialise the RAM contents automatically.  If you google you can find pre-made boards with a small FPGA, config memory, power supplies, etc for not too ridiculous prices.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a universal programmer that can not program newer Xilinx GPGAs than Spartan II !!!  What should I do? change my programmer or Spartan II may do the job? ( XC2S100 is also a cheaper device )

Comment: I guess it depends what you can find. You'd have to pay $50-100 for a modern programmer (Digikey show the HS2 at AU$72). I doubt the XC2S will run at 100MHz, but the XC6S certainly should for a simple design like a DDS.

Comment: and Do I need an external eeprom anymore?

Comment: Yes, you need external non-volatile memory (some serial EEPROM's are suitable, or a platform Flash chip like the XCF series).  Also, you will generally need at least two and sometimes three voltages (1.2V, 3.3V typically, sometimes 2.5V as well).  Consider something like this - it has power conversion, flash memory, USB-JTAG programmer, all built in and ready to go: http://www.em.avnet.com/en-us/design/drc/Pages/Xilinx-Spartan-6-FPGA-LX9-MicroBoard.aspx

Comment: Thanks! That is great. As I am absolutely newbie in FPGA, I think to start with a simpler Xilinx and keep my programmer at this time and then move to higher designs ( I should watch my budget!). Could you please look at XC2S100 datasheet, page 2,Line6. It says it supports up to 200MHz. Is that the system clock? http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds001.pdf

Comment: 200MHz is the absolute maximum flat out speed it can go with very simple logic, say, a single inverter.  With a DDS, my guess is you'd be lucky to get 20MHz.  Newer FPGA's aren't really any more complex to use, they're just bigger, faster, cheaper; compare an XC2S100 (200MHz, 100K gates) to an XC6SLX9 (1080MHz, 500K gates); but they're about the same price from Digikey.

Comment: Thanks! I got my answer and marked this post as correct answer. would you please take a look at this new post? Appreciations again! http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a memory to control a counter (that actually is a adder) you can use a counter to control (=address) consecutive data in a memory.

Example devices from Analog Devices are e.g. AD9833, AD9850.

Comment: For 32 bits resolution it takes 2^32 memory updates. It takes multiple seconds up to minutes to change the frequency  by this method

Comment: That is not true in general. If the output frequency is a rational (i.e. m/n) multiple of the clock frequency (where m and n are small integers) you need much fewer sample values. BTW you didn't tell much about your requirements about changing frequency at all.

Comment: @Aug: for DSS example devices from AD see my edited response.